# ClearScript - scripts that refer to this

Tags: c#, clearscript

How does one use scripts that refer to *this* (in the context of a top level *window* or *global*) in them? For example, the following uses the *V8ScriptEngine* to refer to *this*:

```
engine.Execute(
    new DocumentInfo() { Category = ModuleCategory.Standard },
    @"  
        //  Logger is a dotnet class that wraps Debug.Output. 
        Logger.Write('isDef: ' + isDef(this)); // logs 'false'
       
        function isDef(obj) {
            if(obj === undefined || obj === null) {
                return 'false';
            } else {
                return 'true';
            }
        }
    "
);
```

So far I have been unable to run scripts that refer to *this*. It is pretty common for scripts to refer to *this* (meaning as some sort of top level like *window* or *global*) so I am hoping I just missed something. I basically want to trick the script into thinking that  *this* exists (via polifill, settings, etc).

Comment: I think [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) says it all ?    (Please add a [mre] of some code where `this` fails, together with expected output...)

Comment: @Luuk the example I provided fails. In ModuleCategory.Standard, this is undefined. My question is really about the ClearScript environment in general and dealing with scripts that refer to this.

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have been unable to run scripts that refer to *this*.

As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (about half way down), `this` is always `undefined` at the top level of a module. You can use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) however.

> It is pretty common for scripts to refer to *this*

AFAIK, that's true for normal scripts but not modules. Does your script have to run as a module?

Comment: It seems you cannot combine DocumentCategory and ModuleCategory documents. You can also not require CommonJS modules from inside Standard modules but you can import them. You can't go the other direction I guess. I have a third party script that needs this or it fails.

Comment: Your third-party script uses "this", "require", and "import"? Where does it run now?

Comment: The script supports running under node or in browser. ClearScript supports loading commonjs from es6 scripts but not the other way around.